WinUI 3 Community Toolkit: Undefined namespace XAML
I am a newbie to WinUI 3 and I have a struggle using Community Toolkit SettingsCard. I can't import SettingsCard in xaml. Is there something wrong with my dotnet sdk version or something.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="name.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:name"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:control="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <controls:SettingsCard x:Name="settingsCard"
                               Description="This is a default card, with the Header, HeaderIcon, Description and Content set."
                               Header="This is the Header"></controls:SettingsCard>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>name</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkVersion('$(TargetFramework)')) &gt;= 8">win-x86;win-x64;win-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkVersion('$(TargetFramework)')) &lt; 8">win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PublishProfile>win-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\StoreLogo.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls.SettingsControls" Version="8.1.240916" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22621.756" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.6.240923002" />
    <Manifest Include="$(ApplicationManifest)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!--
    Defining the "Msix" ProjectCapability here allows the Single-project MSIX Packaging
    Tools extension to be activated for this project even if the Windows App SDK Nuget
    package has not yet been restored.
  -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(DisableMsixProjectCapabilityAddedByProject)'!='true' and '$(EnableMsixTooling)'=='true'">
    <ProjectCapability Include="Msix" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!--
    Defining the "HasPackageAndPublishMenuAddedByProject" property here allows the Solution
    Explorer "Package and Publish" context menu entry to be enabled for this project even if
    the Windows App SDK Nuget package has not yet been restored.
  -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(DisableHasPackageAndPublishMenuAddedByProject)'!='true' and '$(EnableMsixTooling)'=='true'">
    <HasPackageAndPublishMenu>true</HasPackageAndPublishMenu>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

To add SettingsCard in WinUI 3 XAML

Rollback from version 8.1 to 8.0. It will work

This is mentioned in the release notes and in the repo. Instead of rolling back to a previous version, try the following:

In your project file(*.csproj), update the target Windows version to 22621.
For example:
From:
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
<WindowsSdkPackageVersion>10.0.19041.38</WindowsSdkPackageVersion>

To:
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFramework>
<WindowsSdkPackageVersion>10.0.22621.38</WindowsSdkPackageVersion>


Also check your publishing profile xml files (*.pubxml) and update the Windows target version if have any there.

Close Visual Studio and reopen your project or Unload/Reload your project.



Didn't this approach work?
